# Convert Macro String to SAS Numeric date

Tags: sql, date, sas

I have got a macro variable which takes a string to feed into a SQL query and I need to convert it to numeric.

Here what I have

```
%let date = '30/11/2017';
```

And I need it to be converted to numeric. I have already find how to convert it to ddmmyy10. or other date formats but I don't know how to transform it to numeric.

Comment: What do you mean by numeric, it would be better to show how you're planning to use the date. If you're manually typing it out why not create it as: `%let date = '30Nov2017'd;` SAS will interpret this as a SAS date, numeric with a date format.

Comment: Also, to add to Reeza's comment, if you intend to use the date in a macro you will need to use `%sysevalf('30Nov2017'd);` which will give you the numeric SAS date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `input()` function to convert the string to a number, and then you can format the number as a date:

```
%let date = '30/11/2017';

data _null_;
 dd = input(&date,ddmmyy10.);
 put dd;
 put dd date9.;
run;
```

which produces:

```
 21153
 30NOV2017
```

Or, if you do as Reeza suggested, you can assign a macro string representing a date literal to a variable directly:

```
%let date = '30NOV2017'd;

data _null_;
 dd = &date ;
 put dd;
 put dd date9.;
run;
```

Which produces the same results.